# Conversion failed when convertion the carchar value '{0}' to data type int

Tags: c#, sql-server

I write simple code to insert some data into MSSQL but i get some error like question title:

> Conversion failed when convertion the carchar value '{0}' to data type
>   int.

This is my dbc class to make connect

```
 public dbc()
    {
        conn = new SqlConnection();
        conn.ConnectionString = connectionString;
        cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Connection = conn;
        da = new SqlDataAdapter();
        dt = new DataTable();
    }
    void connect()
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Closed)
            conn.Open();
    }
    void disconnect()
    {
        if (conn.State == ConnectionState.Open)
            conn.Close();
    }

    public string runQuery(string SQL)
    {
        string result = "";
        cmd.CommandText = SQL;
        connect();
        try
        {
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            result = "null";
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            result = ex.Message.ToString();

        }
        disconnect();
        return result;
    }
    public DataTable retQuery(string SQL)
    {   
        connect();
        try
        {
            cmd.CommandText = SQL;
            da.SelectCommand.Connection = conn;
            da.SelectCommand.CommandText = cmd.CommandText;
            cmd.ExecuteReader();
            da.Fill(dt);
            return dt;
        }
        catch
        {
            return null;
        }
        finally
        {
            disconnect();
        }
    }
}
```

And I do insert operation like this :

```
string SQL =@"INSERT INTO tbl_emp (empid,empname,empmaried,empclass,empdate) VALUES('{0}','{1}','{2}','{3}','{4}')";
string.Format(SQL,Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),textBox2.Text.ToString(),
            comboBox1.SelectedItem,comboBox2.SelectedItem,
            dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
dbc db = new dbc();
var sign = db.runQuery(SQL);
if ( sign == "null")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Done!", "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
}
else
{
    MessageBox.Show(sign.ToString(), "", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
}
```

Comment: Use parameterized statements instead this kind of string operations. That will handle that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is because of using `'` for you non-character fields like `empid`,
Use `{0}` instead of `'{0}'` for your non-character fields of your table.

And also add a `SQL =` before next line like this:

```
SQL = string.Format(SQL,Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text),textBox2.Text.ToString(),
        comboBox1.SelectedItem,comboBox2.SelectedItem,
        dateTimePicker1.Value.ToString());
```

Comment: I did that but i get some error : Incorrect Syntax near 0.